# Laravel 9 - casting json column from/to array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to cast a json column named "incremento_por_persona" but always retun a string.

I add a cast on my "Tarifa" model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'incremento_por_persona' => 'array'
];
```

On controller, I have an array with some data:

```
        foreach ($request->minimoPersonas as $key => $value) {
            $incrementosPorPersona[$key]['minimo_personas'] = $value;
            $incrementosPorPersona[$key]['maximo_personas'] = $request->maximoPersonas[$key];
            $incrementosPorPersona[$key]['precio_incremento'] = $request->precioIncremento[$key];
            $incrementosPorPersona[$key]['tipo_incremento'] = $request->tipoIncremento[$key];
        }
```

And save this array without encoding:

```
Tarifa->incremento_por_persona= $incrementosPorPersona;
Tarifa->save();
```

The result saved on this column is like this:

[{"minimo_personas":"1","maximo_personas":"2","precio_incremento":"12","tipo_incremento":"1"},{"minimo_personas":"2","maximo_personas":"3","precio_incremento":"13","tipo_incremento":"1"}]

The "tarifa" table is an intermediate table, so I collect the field through a model pivot.
But it is always returning a string, I can't receive an array.

```
public function propiedades(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Propiedad::class, Tarifa::class, 'info_tarifa_id', 'id')->withPivot('incremento_por_persona');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rewrite getters and setters for the field.
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator

You need something similar to:

```
protected function incrementoPorPersona(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
        get: fn ($value) => json_decode($value, true),
        set: fn ($value) => json_encode($value),
    );
}
```

Comment: I can't simply use a cast "array"? https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

Comment: JSON is string, not array. Not sure if laravel knows that you are trying to cast JSON to array.